How to have a seperate Data file from Resolver in Graphql using Next.js 14 and React (TS)?
I am using React (typescript) with Next.js 14 (app router) . I want to create a CRUD , data manipulation using Graphql (apollo server\client) . In the resolver I have the data, however is it the resolver file, where the manipulation of data should be happening? Is it a good practice or do I create a seperate file with data?
For the latter , what is the approach? I am new to all these tech stack and managed to set up so far.
TypeDef.ts 
import { ApolloServer } from "@apollo/server";
import { gql } from "graphql-tag";

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`;

export default typeDefs;

resolvers.ts

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
      hello: () => 'world',
    },
  };  
  
  export default resolvers;

Route.ts
import typeDefs from './typeDefs';
import resolvers from './resolvers';
import { gql } from "graphql-tag";
import { startServerAndCreateNextHandler } from "@as-integrations/next";    

const graphql = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,       
  });

  export const config = {
    api: {
      bodyParser: false,
    },
  };
  
const handler = startServerAndCreateNextHandler(graphql);      
export { handler as GET, handler as POST }; 


Unclear what you're asking. Resolvers typically read/write to some kind of database. Also resolvers don't care about front-end stacks like react etc…

So if I have a local Json file, how does it work?

Local to your server I presume? Then you need to use node functions such as fs to read/write it.
